# From a list to a table

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of thousands of lines of the following type:

```
NAME1
SURNAME1

NAME2
SURNAME2

NAME3
SURNAME3
```

which I would like to transform into a two-column table of the following type:

```
NAME1   SURNAME1
NAME2   SURNAME2
NAME3   SURNAME3
```

The intent is to do it through a "regular expression" in `Notepad++`, but I have no idea how to do it and after several searches I had to bother you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

**Find** : `(.+?)\r\n(.+?)\r\n`
**replace** : `\1 \2` (add as many separating blanks as required)

Explanation:

- `(.+?)` : group containing at least one character.
  The `?` denotes lazy match (meaning match as little as possible)
- `\r\n` : end-of-line (on Windows)
- `\1` : value of the first group.

Ensure that your settings match the ones in my dialog:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!